# Необходимо ли тире во фразе?

Tags: грамматика, пунктуация

Подскажите, необходимо ли тире во фразе: "Из пользователя — в создателя"? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Your sentence can be written both ways, with the em dash and without, depending on context. Could you please provide more context? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In an example "Он превратился из пользователя в создателя" you don't need dash at all.

But if it is an article title "Из пользователя - в создателя", if this is the final meaning of the message, which has a little bit mystery and pathos, in this case the dash can be used. But it's not nessesary even here. I think it's all about pause between two parts of the sentense.

This is not "professional" consultation but just direct answer to your question.